# XPath works in browser, but not in simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, xpath, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to parse a specific object which contain a certain string. using XPathHelper i've created below XPath which works fine in on the site however when I try to do it programatically. it returns nothing?

What could trigger this

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$gosu_full = file_get_html("http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/news/30998-  cph-wolves-disbands-cs-go-team");

echo $gosu_full->find("//em[contains(text(), 'More content on GosuGamers:')]", 0);
```

When I just do this

```
echo $gosu_full->find("//em", 0);
```

it returns

```
<em>More content on GosuGamers:</em>
```

Comment: Have you checked what `$gosu_full` looks like after `file_get_html`?

Comment: yes and if i `echo $gosu_full->find("//em", 0)` it returns `<em>More content on GosuGamers:</em>`

Comment: I guess it might be an issue with `simple_html_dom.php`. It works well with the standard PHP DOM.

Comment: just strange the contains function in xpath does not work?

Comment: I guess that `simple_html_dom.php` does not fully implement XPath.

Comment: Okay is there any alternative to retrieve that element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with PHP DOM instead of with `simple_html_dom.php` as follows:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// loadHTMLFile generates many warnings, so we want to suppress them
@$doc->loadHTMLFile("http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/news/30998-  cph-wolves-disbands-cs-go-team");

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//em[contains(text(), 'More content on GosuGamers:')]");

echo $elements->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

However, you do not need `[contains(text(), 'More content on GosuGamers:')]` at all here, so you can reduce it to just:

```
$elements = $xpath->query("//em");
```

and have the same effect.